# rake db:seed throwing error when trying to seed multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to run `rake db:seed` with a file that is meant to populate two tables:

```
User.destroy_all
Profile.destroy_all

User.create! [
  { username: "Fiorina",  password_digest: "xxx" },
  { username: "Trump", password_digest: "yyy" },
  { username: "Carson", password_digest: "zzz" },
  { username: "Clinton", password_digest: "aaa" }
]

Profile.create! [
  { gender: "f", birth_year: "1954", first_name: "Carly", last_name: "Fiorina" }
  { gender: "m", birth_year: "1946", first_name: "Donald", last_name: "Trump" }
  { gender: "m", birth_year: "1951", first_name: "Ben", last_name: "Carson" }
  { gender: "f", birth_year: "1947", first_name: "Hillary", last_name: "Clinton" }
]
```

If I just run the `User.create!` portion it works. However, adding the `Profile.create!` portion throws an error:

```
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: /Users/msnyder/bin/JHRoR/scratch/todolists/db/seeds.rb:22: syntax error, unexpected {, expecting ']'
  { gender: "m", birth_year: "19...
   ^
/Users/msnyder/bin/JHRoR/scratch/todolists/db/seeds.rb:25: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting end-of-input
```

I've double-checked and all brackets/braces are matched up. There shouldn't be any reason for this to fail as far as I can tell.

Comment: you're missing `,` `{ gender: "f", birth_year: "1954", first_name: "Carly", last_name: "Fiorina" },`

Comment: Holy smokes... Thanks /facepalm. Please post this in an answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're missing a comma `,`

```
Profile.create! [
  { gender: "f", birth_year: "1954", first_name: "Carly", last_name: "Fiorina" },
  { gender: "m", birth_year: "1946", first_name: "Donald", last_name: "Trump" },
  { gender: "m", birth_year: "1951", first_name: "Ben", last_name: "Carson" },
  { gender: "f", birth_year: "1947", first_name: "Hillary", last_name: "Clinton" }
]
```